# Mobile view issues with iphones

Tags: android, html, css, ios

I have an issue with mobile views on iphones. On android devices everything works fine. I also tried to set the specific width and height for iphone xr but it still doesn't work.

I have tested my website in google mobile friendly test and everything was ok.

This is my code that works perfectly for android devices with max-width 700px:

```
body {
       background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/ass-1.png');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: center center;
       background-attachment: fixed;
       background-size: cover;
   }   
   
   
   @media screen and (max-width: 700px) { 
 body {
   background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/mobiledevicelogo2.png');
     background-position: fixed;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**iPhone XR** having resolution `max-width:414px`

[image]

More info : https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width/

```
@media screen and (min-width: 414px) { 
 body {
   background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/mobiledevicelogo2.png');
     background-position: fixed;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
 }
```

Comment: That means that I must add a code for XR too ? Or just change the first one ?

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 414) { } use this this only take all devlces min-width=414,,
.For more info : https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Comment: updated in answer replace with existing media queries..

Comment: Still does not work :( What about (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3) ? Should I add it to "@media screen and (min-width: 414) and" ?

Comment: check now 414 give it 414px

Comment: On all android devices works fine , but IOS devices are just ruining my website :(